# Using a system call to execute "which" command in C

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to get the pathname for specific user input. For example, if the user inputs ls | wc I want to create two strings the first one being a which(ls), and the second one being a which(wc) so I have the pathname. I am doing this inside a C program and my code looks like the following.

```
/*This is a basic example of what i'm trying to do*/

char* temp;
printf("Enter a command\n");
/* assume user enters ls */
scanf("%s", temp);        
char* path = system(which temp);
printf("Testing proper output: %s\n", path);

/*I should be seeing "/bin/ls" but the system call doesn't work properly*/
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `scanf("%s", temp);` has no memory allocated: `temp` is uninitialised too, so it's an invalid pointer on both counts.

Comment: You want `popen` not `system`. You also want to enable warnings for your compiler, and treat them as errors. If you are using gcc, try `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: popen opens a process by creating a pipe. It doesnt look like it will give me the pathname or am I missing something? I'm not trying to execute the command just trying to see the path.

Comment: Yes you are definitely missing something. Let's start with the obvious. Will `system` give you a pathname? Why or why not? Hint: what type does it return?

Comment: Both `system` and `popen` take a single string as the definition of the command to execute.  At some point there needs to be something like `char cmd[1024]; sprintf( cmd, "which %s", temp );` and then use `cmd` as the command argument to `popen`

Comment: RTM. `int system(const char *command);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an uninitialized pointer. But even if you had initialized it properly, it still wouldn't work because `system()` doesn't return the output of the command it executes.
You want to use [`popen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to do that.

Here's an example (untested):

```
if (fgets(cmd, sizeof cmd, stdin)) {
   char cmd[512];
   cmd[strcspn(cmd, "\n")] = 0; // in case there's a trailing newline
   char which_cmd[1024];
   snprintf(which_cmd, sizeof which_cmd, "which %s", cmd);
   char out[1024];
   FILE *fp = popen(which_cmd);
   if (fp && fgets(out, sizeof out, fp)) {
      printf("output: %s\n", out);
   }
}
```

Comment: `snprintf(which_cmd, sizeof(which_cmd), "which %s", cmd);` I think

Comment: @infixed Thanks. Fixed now.